# TypoScript MenuProcessor special = directory :: page type shortcut

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I've defined the following typoscript or my ce:

```
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
    10 {
        special = directory
        special.value.field = pages
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            10 {
                references.fieldName = media
            }
            20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            20 {
                references.fieldName = teaser_image
                as = teaserImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The value for pages comes from the configuration in the be (select page from pagetree).

This works well, but if a page with type shortcut (4) is selected, nothing will be generated. I am looking for a way to achieve that if a shortcut is selected, the menu for the target page of this shortcut is being generated.

I want to solve this explicitly for the page type shortcut, not for the page type mountpoint. Unfortunately, I still don't get any data in the variable menu when the page type is shortcut.

Comment: Ehm, that is the behavior of CE "Menu -> Pages" (CType 'menu_pages'). With a (valid) target page in the shortcut, "Menu -> Pages" has listed both my pages (normal page and shortcut). 
You are struggling over the inner `dataProcessing`and missing its content, right?

Answer (score 0):

For clarification that's the whole typoscript for the ce:

```
 ############################################
#### CTYPE:menu_distribution ####
############################################
tt_content.menu_distribution =< lib.contentElement
tt_content.menu_distribution {
    templateName = MenuDistribution
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
            special = directory
            special.value.field = pages
            as = menu
            dataProcessing {
                10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = media
                }
                20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                20 {
                    references.fieldName = teaser_image
                    as = teaserImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stdWrap {
        editIcons = tt_content: header [header_layout], pages
        editIcons {
            iconTitle.data = LLL:EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Language/FrontendEditing.xlf:editIcon.menu
        }
    }
}
```

In the template for the ce the variable menu contains nothing, if a page of type shortcut is selected.

TCA:

```
'pages' => [
                'exclude' => true,
                'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.startingpoint',
                'config' => [
                    'type' => 'group',
                    'internal_type' => 'db',
                    'allowed' => 'pages',
                    'size' => 3,
                    'maxitems' => 1,
                    'minitems' => 1
                ]
            ],
```

Comment: Please edit/update your initial post for clarification instead of posting an answer (which does not answers/resolves the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, your shortcut is visible in menus?

The FSCs CE "Menu -> Subpages" (CType 'menu_pages') does nearly the same:

```
# Menu of subpages of selected pages:
# ...
#
# CType: menu_subpages

tt_content.menu_subpages =< lib.contentElement
tt_content.menu_subpages {
    templateName = MenuSubpages
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
            special = directory
            special.value.field = pages
            dataProcessing {
                10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = media
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in a test (TYPO3 v10), this CE shows me standard-pages *and* shortcuts.

---

Maybe, you are confusing "Shortcut" and "Mountpoint"...

### Example

[image: Simple pagetree with pages, shortcut and mountpoint]

Selecting "Page 2" in the `pages` field of Contentelement "Subpages" (CType `menu_subpages`) is showing:

- Page 2.1
- Page 2.2

Selecting "Page 4" (which is of type "Shortcut" and pointing to "Page 2") is showing its own subpages:

- Page 4.1

Selecting "Page 5" (which is of type "Mountpoint" and *mounting* "Page 2") is showing the subpages of the *mounted* page:

- Page 2.1
- Page 2.2